# Benchmark data sets for anomaly detection algorithms in multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, references, multivariate-analysis, dataset, anomaly-detection

as per title, which datasets are commonly used to benchmark novel methods to detect anomalies in multivariate time series? I'm particularly interested in moderately high-dimensional (10-40 components), very long time series (preferably, from 10^4 to 10^6 samples).